# Why sharp cutoff RG introduces long range interaction and smooth cutoff doesn't

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

In momentum shell RG we introduce a sharp momentum cutoff, and integrate out those high momentum modes to get an effective action. I heard that this kind of RG will introduce long range interaction, and smooth cutoff RG can avoid this problem.  Can anyone explain in detail why sharp cutoff introduces long range interaction and smooth cutoff doesn't?

Comment: Can you give a source? I haven't heard about long range interactions introduced by the cut-off. Could you be confusing this with electrodynamics in the Coulomb gauge that has long range interactions? One possible explanation I see is that the cut-off is not Lorentz invariant (you have $p_0^2 + {\bf p}^2 \le \Lambda^2$ which uses the Euclidean metric instead of Minkowski, and you can't replace it with Minkowski as the integrals will run to infinity which defies the purpose of the cut-off). If by "smooth" you mean something like Pauli-Villars, then it is Lorentz invariant.

Comment: Just an FYI, smooth cutoff (with a characteristic energy scale $\Lambda$) is employed by Polchinski's functional/exact renormalization group approach to evade pathologies associated with sharp momentum cutoff.

Comment: @MadMax Could you please specify what's the pathologies of sharp momentum cutoff?

Comment: @张炳南, see, e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.05749, for the grievances against "the notorious sharp momentum cutoff".